# Is there a cleaner way to code multiple markers on a leaflet map in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, markers

I currently have 6 individually coded markers on my leaflet map in javascript. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to code all these and just change the coordinates? (Below is an example of 2 of the markers I have in my Javascript code)

```
var circle = L.circle([20, 20], {
color: 'red',
fillColor: '#f03',
fillOpacity: 0.5,
radius: 100
```

}).addTo(map).bindPopup('House');

```
var circle = L.circle([30, 30], {
color: 'red',
fillColor: '#f03',
fillOpacity: 0.5,
radius: 100
```

}).addTo(map).bindPopup('House');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of Course, you can make simple function and use it.

```js
function addHouse(x, y, map) {
  return L.circle([x, y], {
           color: 'red',
           fillColor: '#f03',
           fillOpacity: 0.5,
           radius: 100
         }).addTo(map).bindPopup('House');
}

const circle1 = addHouse(20, 20, map);
const circle2 = addHouse(30, 30, map);
```

Comment: Thanks alot!  Would you also know how to hide/show these markers